# How to format a 20 digits numbers in GSHEETS (or EXCEL)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, number-formatting

I am using GSHEETS
I am trying to use a format number to customise the display of a 
20 digits number, example:
Input in the cell: 12345678901234567890
desired cell formatting: 12 345678 9012345678 90
I tried this: 00_000000_0000000000_00
but it dipslays 12 345678 9012345000 00
I tried this: 00"-"000000"-"00000000"-"00
but it displays this: 1234-567890-12345000-00
It seems that it's possible to format only 15 numbers. Is that right or am I mistaking?

Comment: You will need to treat it as a text string and not a number.  the apps only store 15 sig digits in numbers.

Comment: Hello scott isn't the a possibility of formatting with @ ?

Comment: the cell has to be formatted as text string BEFORE entering/pasting/importing the data into the cell.  If done after the numbers after the 15th sig digit is gone and not retrievable.

Comment: ok thank you I will put the two cells and use the solution of kishkin or a html input box and proceed to preformat the the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a Google Sheets only solution.

If you have a 20 digit number in a cell and it is effectively a string, then this will format it as you need it (it still will be a string):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^(\d{2})(\d{6})(\d{10})(\d{2})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4")
```

[image]

**UPDATE.** And here are a few others.

Not only a number but any string will be formatted with spaces:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2, "^(.{2})(.{6})(.{10})(.{2})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4")
```

This one lets you change the delimiter in one place:

```
=JOIN(" ", REGEXEXTRACT(B4, "^(\d{2})(\d{6})(\d{10})(\d{2})$"))
```

And a silly one:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B3, "^(..)(......)(..........)(..)$", "$1 $2 $3 $4")
```

[image]

Comment: ugly as all get out to read, but it works, but that is regex for you

Comment: i wish SO had a laugh emojis! the beauty is in the power, not the syntax :)

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,19,0," "),9,0," "),3,0," ")
```

[image]

Comment: upvoted: slightly more readable then `^(\d{2})(\d{6})(\d{10})(\d{2})$` .... but only slightly (hahaha)

Answer (score 1):

Use two cells.

With the full 20 character numeral-string in cell **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & " " & MID(A1,3,6) & " " & MID(A1,9,10) & " " & RIGHT(A1,2)
```

[image]

This will work just as well with a 20 character alphabetic string.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you working string values, maybe:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,MID(A1,{1,3,9,19},{2,6,10,2}))
```

Or even:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,{1;3;9;19},{2;6;10;2})&" ")
```

I believe for Google-Sheets you'd need `CONCATENATE`.